# Parse a png image into many png images in J2ME

Tags: java-me

Can anyone tell me how i can parse a png image into many png images in J2ME ? I want to write a code that take a image and give many images that have equal pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to cut it into smaller images?

1. Load the image.
2. Convert to a bitmap.
3. Encode arbitrary rectangles as PNG.
4. Save the PNGs.

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about image processing usinf J2ME libraries.

[Here's what I googled as far as loading a PNG in J2ME.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/ViewPng2.htm)

Using that, you'll be able to see the API calls used, and following the `import` list, you'll get to the classes used. Look at those class's methods, and yu'll probably come up with what you need.

I did this mostly because you're having an emergency, but frankly, you could have googled this yourself, *or* composed a question that was clearer, which would have led to someone more knowledgeable about J2ME image processing helping you.

Just don't panic, take a breath, google for what you need, you'll be fine.